# How to open Control Panel in python using win32 extension

Tags: python, windows, winapi

I am interested in being able to open the control panel through python using the win32 extension.

What I really want to be able to do is open the 'Internet Properties' panel (Control Panel > Network and Internet > Internet Options), but I'd figured getting the control panel open would be a good enough start.

For those using Chrome, if you go to Menu > Settings > Show Advanced Settings > Change proxy settings...  , the Windows 'Internet Properties' box shows us.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144191%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) page and [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/149648) one, you could use something like:

```
import win32api
import win32con

win32api.WinExec(
    '{0}\\control.exe Inetcpl.cpl'.format(win32api.GetSystemDirectory()),
    win32con.SW_NORMAL
)

# or

win32api.WinExec('control.exe Inetcpl.cpl', win32con.SW_NORMAL)
```

Internet Options dialog should pops up now.

Yon don't really need win32 extension for this, you can use something as simple as:

```
import os

os.system('{0}\\System32\\control.exe Inetcpl.cpl'.format(os.environ['WINDIR']))

# or

os.system('control.exe Inetcpl.cpl')
```

Comment: @user1129665, What if I want to open control panel, Go to default programs and select google chrome? Can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

```py
import os
from tkinter import *

def open():
     os.system('cmd /c control') # thi is what will help you

root =Tk()
root.geometry('400x400')
b = Button(root, text='open control panel', command = (open)).place(x=200, y=200) # you can choose your own position 

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.